# Xalan transformer not inserting newlines/formatting the output.

Tags: xalan

Xalan transformer not inserting newlines/formatting the output. Is there any method/class in Xalan which formats the out properly ?

Answer (score 1):

To make XSL out indented …
Add xalan names space  to stylesheet and indent attributes to xsl:output element

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"  xalan:indent-amount="5"/>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for.Thanks!